Conditionally join rows in SQL based on a date value being in or not being in a start/end range
I have two tables:
Table A, names are unique



Name
Color




Alex
Red


Beck
Yellow


Cora
Blue



Table B, has addresses and a start/end date representing when the person lived at each address



Name
Address
Start
End




Alex
41 Andover St
2023-01-15
2023-06-08


Alex
8 Lexington Dr
2023-06-08
2023-09-17


Alex
3 Sutor Ave
2023-09-17
NULL


Beck
349 Laurel Rd
2023-08-09
2023-09-23


Beck
155 Country Club Dr
2023-09-23
NULL


Cora
227 Henry Smith St
2022-12-19
NULL



I would like to join these two tables based on a date value passed to the query. If an address was active for that date value, use it. If no addresses are found, then use the earliest active address.
Example 1, date value passed to query is 2023-01-31:



Name
Color
Address




Alex
Red
41 Andover St


Beck
Yellow
349 Laurel Rd


Cora
Blue
227 Henry Smith St



Example 2, date value passed to query is 2023-09-30:



Name
Color
Address




Alex
Red
3 Sutor Ave


Beck
Yellow
155 Country Club Dr


Cora
Blue
227 Henry Smith St



So far I have only written queries that join records when the date value exists in the start/end ranges:
SELECT *
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b ON a.name=b.name
AND b.start <= '2024-01-31'
AND (b.end IS NULL OR b.end >= '2024-01-31')

I am not sure how to add the second part where it joins to the earliest active address if no records match. Is this possible using only SQL? I am querying in Snowflake if relevant.

So if you build a CTE that has the first per person, then you can LEFT JOIN this as well as the in date range. Then you can use NVL2 to pick the value based on the exact match success:
with table_a(name, color) as (
    select * from values
        ('Alex', 'Red'),
        ('Beck', 'Yellow'),
        ('Cora', 'Blue')
), table_b(name, address, start_d, end_d) as (
    select * from values
        ('Alex', '41 Andover St', '2023-01-15', '2023-06-08'),
        ('Alex', '8 Lexington Dr', '2023-06-08', '2023-09-17'),
        ('Alex', '3 Sutor Ave', '2023-09-17', NULL),
        ('Beck', '349 Laurel Rd', '2023-08-09', '2023-09-23'),
        ('Beck', '155 Country Club Dr', '2023-09-23', NULL),
        ('Cora', '227 Henry Smith St', '2022-12-19', NULL)
), dates(date_d) as (
    select * from values
    ('2023-01-31'::date),
    ('2023-09-30'::date)
), first_per_person as (
    select * 
    from table_b
    qualify row_number() over (partition by name order by start_d) = 1
)
SELECT 
    d.*,
    a.*,
    nvl2(b.name, b.address, f.address) as address
    --nvl2(b.name, b.start_d, f.start_d) as start_d,
    --nvl2(b.name, b.end_d, f.end_d) as end_d
FROM dates as d
cross join table_a as a
left join first_per_person as f 
    ON a.name=f.name    
LEFT JOIN table_b as b 
    ON a.name=b.name
        AND b.start_d <= d.date_d
        AND (b.end_d IS NULL OR b.end_d >= d.date_d)
order by 1,2

Here I put both dates into another CTE, just so we could see it all working at the same time.
If you wanted instead of "first" the most resent to the date used, ASOF JOIN is the optimal way to get that.
This code also has the "date start/end" of the row that was used, to show how to use NVL2 to get other values, because the address line could use NVL/COALESCE but that will not work for the end date as that might valid as null, where the primary key name does not make sense to be null.

